# does RCP3 support cascade window functionality?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am beginner of RCP framework. I have used multiple Editor in eclipse RCP3 application.
my editor class like

1. Food Details Editor
2. New Employee Editor
3. Staff details Editor
4. Inquiry Details Editor

When I open multiple in main Editor part via command.multiple editor open in new tab:

[image]

This editor opens cascade pattern like Browser

[image]

is this possible Editor part open in cascade window?

My system configuration:

```
Windows 64Bit OS.
Eclipse Kepler 32 bit.
jdk 1.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in Eclipse RCP for this.

Since an editor is basically just SWT code you can make it open new Shells like this but it would be up to you to arrange them in a cascade.